# Remote dual boot, how to select OS to boot

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, dual-boot, reboot

I'm installing Bootcamp ( Win7 64bit if that matters ) on my Mac Mini, since you need to pick the OS to start up while booting, how can I do this remotely?

Example:

VNC into OSX, reboot the machine, how do I select either OSX or Windows? Is there an option I can pass in while rebooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [BootChamp](http://www.kainjow.com/) to quickly restart in Windows from OS X. To restart in OS X from Windows see [OS X Lion - Start up using Mac OS X or Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4286):

> #### Restart directly in Mac OS X from Windows:
>
> Click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray and choose “Restart in Mac OS X.”

---

A more tedious way is to set the startup disk to the other OS every time and then restart. From the [OS X Lion - Start up using Mac OS X or Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4286) page linked above:

> #### Set the default operating system:
>
> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - In Mac OS X, choose Apple > System Preferences and click Startup Disk.
>    - In Windows, choose Boot Camp Control Panel from the Boot Camp system tray item.
> 2. Select the startup disk with the operating system you want to use by default.
> 3. If you want to start up that operating system now, click Restart.

The Apple support page for [OS X Mountain Lion - Start up using Mac OS X or Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11132) contains the same instructions for OS X Mountain Lion.